Is there an easy way to have a channel that sends in blocking mode, receives in async mode?
Suppose I have a blocking serial port library. I want to send its packets to a channel, but receive async in the other side of the channel.
The way that I thought was:
Have a queue structure to accomodate the packets, a condvard to notify when I put a packet there, and this would wake the async waiter
But is there a simpler way? It looks like the futures channels kinda do this but both sides are async

Tokio channels have blocking_send
